# Transferring files from Windows to Ubuntu on the same machine

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, putty, pscp

I work with PCs. So I installed Ubuntu on a Windows machine as I was told that I need a Linux system to be able to analyze my data. I have a file in a folder on this machine that I need to use Linux commands to work on. How do I use Ubuntu to access this file and work on it? I installed PuTTY and pscp, thinking I need to move the file to a folder in the Ubuntu part of the computer (so I can use Linux commands) but it is not clear how to do so. Can someone help, please? I am new to Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume (same machine) you are using a virtual machine.

Then the connection in Ubuntu is quite simple.

Open Ubuntu File Explorer and look down in Other locations.

Lower right space:   SMB://IPaddressofWindows/folder

See the screen shot below here and I have already made the connection .

[image: Ubuntu connected to Windows]

.

It is easier to map from Ubuntu to Windows (SMB) than from Windows to Ubuntu (SSH and Samba).

.

If using dual boot, just use a USB drive for file interchange between the two operating systems.

..

If you have Linux command line only (life is vastly easier with GUI) try this guide for SMB Client by command line. Pickier than what I posted earlier.

[SMB by command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/smbclien.htm#:%7E:text=Operations%20%20%20%3F%20%5B%20command%5D%20%20,in%20the%20...%20%2025%20more%20rows%20)

Use the smbclient command

Comment: Thank you, @John. Sorry for the delay in my response. You seem to have a GUI for Ubuntu, whereas I only seem to have a command line window with no menu or tabs.

Comment: I would like to show you an image of what I have but I don't seem to be able to add an image. Maybe because I'm new?

Comment: I added an SMB Client howto for you

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out. Appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to see if you can add a GUI manager to your system (Gnome for example) to make things easier for yourself.

Comment: This ^^^ You installed the Server edition which is tailored for actual server tasks and doesn't have a desktop environment because generally it's an unnecessary waste of resources. But for anything else, even typical home usage / SOHO usage "server" tasks - not even the case here - the Desktop edition is preferable. There's no substantial difference between this editions. Any "server" specific software can be installed in Desktop and conversely a DE can be installed in Server.

Comment: Thanks, @John. I will look into Gnome.

Comment: And thanks, @ChanganAuto, but it is not clear how you inferred that I installed the server edition (which might well be true), but I will check out the desktop edition.

Comment: Te main difference being Server (no DE) and Desktop (Gnome DE) it was easy to infer.